# Capturar el valor de un slider en HTML

Tags: javascript, html, liquid

Tengo un slider funcional hecho en HTML y me arroja el valor del slider conforme se mueve (Dentro del rango especificado), pero necesito tomar ese valor y ejecutar una función según dicho valor. Intenté usando la propiedad value para darle el valor a la variable "followers7" y también con getElementByID pero no encuentro otra manera de darle a la variable "followers7" (o que la función capture) el valor del slider, ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo?, ¿Hay algo mal en el código?.

El código html es:

```
<div class="slidecontainer2"> 
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange2" height= "2"> 
  <label>Value: <span id="demo2"/></label><br> 
  <label>Ganancia estimada: <br><input type="number" name="sum7" value="0" readonly="readonly" /></label>
</div>
```

Y el script es:

```
<script>
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange2"),
output = document.getElementById("demo2");
output.innerHTML = slider.value; 

slider.oninput = function Calculate7(){
  output.innerHTML = this.value;
  try{
  var followers7 = document.getElementById("myRange2"),
        followersReached7 = followers7 * 2,
        averageSale7= followersReached7 * 2,
        estimateEarning7= averageSale7 * 2;
  
  document.slidecontainer2.sum7.value = estimateEarning7;
    } catch (e){}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay algunas cosas por corregir:

- No es recomendable asignar funciones a eventos por nombre `elemento.evento`, es mejor usar `addEventListener` que te da mayor flexibilidad, principalmente porque puedes asignar tantos como sean necesarios en lugar de solo 1 como en la primera opción
- Te recomiendo usar el evento `change` en lugar de `input`, suele ser más adecuado en la mayoría de los casos, aunque tal vez no sea tan relevante en este tipo de campo
- No necesitas un bloque `try / catch`, puedes hacer las operaciones usando `parseInt()` y agregando `|| 0` al final para prevenir errores

**Nota:** Cambié el método para seleccionar elementos de `getElementById()` por `querySelector()`; funciona prácticamente igual con ambos, pero en el caso de la suma, resulta mucho más fácil acceder por nombre de campo que buscar primero contenedores previos.

```js
let slider = document.querySelector('#myRange2');
let output = document.querySelector('#demo2');
let earning = document.querySelector('[name="sum7"]');

output.innerHTML = slider.value; 

slider.addEventListener('change', function() {
    output.textContent = this.value;
    earning.value = parseInt(this.value * 6) || 0;
});
```

```html
<div class="slidecontainer2"> 
  <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50" class="slider" id="myRange2" height= "2"> 
  <label>Value: <span id="demo2"/></label><br> 
  <label>Ganancia estimada: <br><input type="number" name="sum7" value="0" readonly="readonly" /></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Funcionó, muchas gracias por las correcciones, tendré en cuenta esos detalles a partir de ahora